Caulking Bathtub and Wall Surround to prevent water leak
I have a two piece bathtub and wall surround kit(similar to this one) that the crack is causing excess water to drain out to where the wall and tub meet. I am thinking I should put a bead of 100% silicon caulk in the crack to prevent the water from making its way to the dry wall, is that a suitable fix?


That should have been caulked during the initial installation, not after damage has been done.  You'll also want to caulk the whole perimeter of the tub where the surround is, not just on that side.

This is exactly why I use oil based primers in bathrooms.   This is exactly the water damage you get with latex primers.

@Milwrdfan unfortunately this was installed before we owned the home.

Yes, caulking the joint with 100% silicon will help if the issue is that water is getting into the gap and draining out the side.
If the issue is water getting past the shower curtain or kids splashing, you may want to look into also adding a bathtub corner guard.


Tremendous, thank you so much for your help!
